# audio streaming extention with no save option? (joomla 1.0)

Tags: joomla, joomla-extensions

I need to publish a audio file that I want to make available to

```
* listen and
* not to download
```

any idea how to do it? Is there any free joomla extention plugin for that?

Something where user cannot save the audo using any webbrowser plugin like DownloadHelper etc.

Comment: Any system that allows listening will allow downloading/saving of some form, even if the user has to use a microphone on their speakers.  Protection against browser plugins is possible, but be aware that nothing will be 100% download-proof, and nothing will remain plugin-proof forever.

Comment: @reemrevnivek: I'm aware of that and would be happy with any protection against browser plugins.

Comment: right now I would be happy for any audio streaming plugin/extention/module for Joomla 1.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way I can think of is to use the JoomlaWorks extension AllVideos. It has support for audio files and very easy to set up and use.

Comment: does it offer protection against browser plugins that allows user to save the video/audio?

Comment: I does not, and I just realized you are looking for J!1.0, which this is not compatible. You will certainly have to code something yourself since J!1.0 has been obsolete for over a year now. I seriously doubt anyone is developing anything for it actively.

Comment: I had to update my question after I logged into my friend's Joomla admin and realiased it runs on J!1.0. I found an old version of Media player http://joomlaplay.com/ I installed it but I cannot make it work. I am not a Joomla guy :-)

Comment: TBH it's been so long since I did anything in 1.0 it would probably be faster to upgrade the site!